# Perl equivalent of bash command

Tags: perl

I am not familiar with perl script, but i need an equivalent to the follow line of bash:

file1 contains a string with multiple words like:

```
<Description>string string string</Description>
```

file2 contains a string with multiple words in the second column like:

```
Description         string string string
```

```
if [[ -e $file1 ]]; then

var1=cat $file1 | grep Description | sed 's/\(.\{13\}\)//' | sed 's/.\{14\}$//'`

elif [[ -e $file2 ]]; then

var1=`cat $file2 | grep Description | cut -f2`

fi
```

Code i tried:

```
if (-e file$1) {
    $var1 .= perl -ne 'print if s/<Description.*>(.*?)<\/Description>/$1/g' file$1;
} else {

if (-e file$2){
   $var1 .= perl -ne 'print if s/Description(.*?)/$1/g' file$2;
}
}
```

Comment: It is expected that you show the Perl code you have tried. See [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for more information

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perl was originally created as a glue language. So the simplest approach is probably to use it like that:

```
my $var;

if (-e $file1) {
  $var1 = `cat $file1 | grep Description | sed 's/\(.\{13\}\)//' | sed 's/.\{14\}$//'`;
} elsif ( -e $file2 ) {
  $var1 = `cat $file2 | grep Description | cut -f2`;
}
```

Something in pure Perl would require opening the files and reading the data.

```
my $var;

if (-e $file1) {
  open my $fh, '<', $file1 or die "Can't open '$file1': $!\n";
  while (<$fh>) {
    if (/Description/) {
      $var1 = $_;
      $var1 =~ s/^.{13}//;
      $var1 =~ s/.{14}^//;
    }
  }
} elsif ( -e $file2 ) {
  open my $fh, '<', $file2 or die "Can't open '$file2': $!\n";
  while (<$fh>) {
    if (/Description/) {
      (undef, $var1) = split /\s+/, $_, 2;
    }
  }
}
```

(I don't have time to test these, so there may be minor typos.)